# Factory Girl trouble with associations/delegated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

While running my tests, I get this error: `Validation failed: User can't be blank (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)`. Pertinent code is here. When I add `user` to the user profile I come up with a circular definition (the tests suddenly finish). I think that a callback is needed, but I'm at wit's end figuring out where. I'd really appreciate the help. :)

models/user.rb

```
has_one :user_profile, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :user
delegate :first_name, :last_name, :sex, :birthday,
  :location, :school, to: :user_profile
```

models/user_profile.rb

```
belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :user_profile
validates :user, presence: true
```

factories.rb

```
factory :user do
  user_profile

end

factory :user_profile do
  first_name Faker::Name.first_name # everything works, I put in the data already.
  # ?????
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve it, finally. What's happening is that both models need each other before they can both be saved. So I added an after build hook to the `user` factory. What I missed was passing the reference to the user itself.

```
factory :user do |user|

    after(:build) do |user|
      create(:user_profile, user: user)
    end

  end

  factory :user_profile do
    association :user
    first_name Faker::Name.first_name
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Create factory like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
   factory :user do
      first_name Faker::Name.first_name
   end
end
```

and

```
FactoryGirl.define do
   factory :user_profile do
      association :user, strategy: :build
   end
end
```

user_profile belongs_to user, so we create association in user_profile.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but when I remove `user_profile` from the `user`I get `User#sex delegated to user_profile.sex, but user_profile is nil`

Comment: If you used delegates then its user_profile_sex instead of user_profile.sex
Use this user_profile.try(:sex) or check condition before it like if user_profile.present?